# @djinn MonadError e m => m ()

Tags: haskell, monads

Is it possible to give an expression of type

```
MonadError e m => m ()
```

that raises an error, that can be handled with `catchError`? Note the absence of an `Error e` requirement.

Under what circumstances can an error created with `fail` be handled with `catchError`? What can lead to a `fail` not being caught by `catchError`? In what way did these circumstances change with respect to GHC releases? (There is a [mention](http://blog.ezyang.com/2011/08/8-ways-to-report-errors-in-haskell-revisited/) that the behaviour changed in base 4.3.)

The background of this question is a larger piece of code ([Igor2](http://www.cogsys.wiai.uni-bamberg.de/effalip/) function `nomatch`) where an error created with `fail "some message"` passes by `catchError` and terminates the program, but replacing the `fail` invocation with `throwError undefined` results in the error being caught as expected. Of course `throwError undefined` is an ugly hack and this question aims to understand the background and correct solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several separate issues here, so I'll go through them in order.

```
MonadError e m => m ()
```

The problem with the above is that if `e` is not constrained in any way, it is impossible to create a value of type `e` which you need for `throwError`. So no, the only valid value for the above type that raises an error would need to include

```
throwError undefined
```

which is a cop-out (and not very useful). The `Error e` constraint lets you leave `e` abstract by providing a mechanism to construct a value of type `e` from a string.

> Under what circumstances can an error created with fail be handled with catchError? What can lead to a fail not being caught by catchError?

This depends entirely of the monad in question. Different instances of `MonadError` might have a different implementation for `fail` so there is no generic answer. Or to put it another way, there are no guarantees that the error triggered by `fail` can be handled by `catchError` unless you are using a specific instance of `MonadError` that makes that promise. For example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

import Control.Monad.Error

example :: (Error e, MonadError e m) => m String
example = fail "This is a failure" `catchError` const (return "Error was caught")

main = do
    example >>= putStrLn
    either putStrLn putStrLn example
```

In the first line of `main`, `example` uses the `MonadError` instance of `IO` and the second line uses the `MonadError` instance of `Either String`. `fail` results in a catchable error in `IO` but not in `Either` so the program outputs

```
Error was caught
*** Exception: This is a failure
```

However, if we replace `example` with

```
example :: (Error e, MonadError e m) => m String
example = throwError (strMsg "This is a failure")
    `catchError` const (return "Error was caught")
```

Then we get the desired output

```
Error was caught
Error was caught
```

And this would work the same for *any* (valid) instance of `MonadError`, unlike `fail`.

> In what way did these circumstances change with respect to GHC releases? (There is a mention that the behaviour changed in base 4.3.)

The change in base 4.3 refers to how `fail` works in the `Either` monad. In previous versions `fail` returned a `Left` value which could be caught with `catchError` but in 4.3 and after it uses [`error`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v%3aerror) and triggers an exception that has to be handled in `IO` (with e.g. [`catch`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v%3acatch)).

The problem in Igor2 sounds like it uses the `Either` monad and assumes the old behavior of `fail`  when it should be using `throwError` (or simply `Left` if there is no suitable `Error` instance).

Comment: Can you also construct a small example where a `fail` goes past a `catchError`?

Comment: @Helmut: Added a simple example.

Comment: Thank you very much for this comprehensive answer that has enabled me to make Igor2 work a lot better with GHC 7. I replaced those failures meant to be caught with `throwError . strMsg` and introduced the `Error e` requirement as necessary. Fortunately all the users of the relevant functions already provided the additional instance.